# First Name - Number/Number regex Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex in java that checks a string for the following format:

"FirstName LastName - Number/Number"

Example :

John John - 66/25

I have been trying for the past half an hour, it seemed so simple but I was not able to get the hang of it. Here is my latest attempt :

```
[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\s{1}[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\s{1}\\-\s{1}[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}
```

Took into consideration checking first letter of both fname and lname. The first and last name part works, but the "-" character and after that dont.

The code the regex is used in :

```
public class Regex {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){

        System.out.println("Enter the regular expression");

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(scan.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter the matcher");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(scan.nextLine());

        boolean success = m.find();

        System.out.println(success);
    }
}
```

Comment: `{1}` is redundant, remove it. --- Why do you have ``\\`` in there? Is this the raw regex (single backslashes), or the Java string literal (all backslashes doubled)? --- It should be `[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s-\s[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}` or `"[A-Z][a-z]+\\s[A-Z][a-z]+\\s-\\s[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}"`

Comment: Yes, please show the actual java code the regex is used in.

Comment: The double backslashes are there for indicating on a special character such as "-"

Comment: The minus character (`-`) is not special in regex outside a character class. Neither is forward slash (`/`), in Java. They don't need escaping, but if they did, escaping is done with a single backslash (``\``).

Comment: You were correct. I used double backslashes for whatever reason and didn't even see the issue here. Time to get some sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double backslash before the dash `\\-` and the forward slash `\\/` actually ended up matching a literal `\`, which is not present in the string you wanted.

Some additional comments:

1. You do not need `{1}` if you only want one match, that's implicit unless anything else is specified.
2. Also dash `-` is not a special character outside character classes, so it does not need escaping.
3. `[0-9]` can be simplified to `\d`

Cleaned up:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+\s-\s\d{2}/\d{2}
```

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/JbkwJS/3